# ASP.NET MVC 2 jquery datepicker format not set

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

In my code I want to set the format of dates to d MM yy. I've tried the following but with no success:

```
$().ready(function () {

        $.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'd MM yy' });


        $("#Client_DateOfBirth").datepicker(
        {
            maxDate: "+0D",
            dateFormat: 'd MM yy'
        });
});
```

The date is set as follows:

```
<div class="registration-item">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model =>model.Client.DateOfBirth) %>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Client.DateOfBirth)%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Client.DateOfBirth) %>
</div>
```

The value is displayed as: 15-8-1988 0:00:00. I don't want this,I want 15 aug 1988.

When I pick a value from the datepicker,I get the right value. But when a value is already set,the format is not applied. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is formatted correctly when you select a date from the datepicker, it means that the date needs formatting when initially put in the input by your ASP code. Try formatting the date like this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Client, new { @Value = model.Client.DateOfBirth.ToString("d MMM yyyy") }) %>
```

[More information of date formatting in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)